# Is Ultra Instinct a Super Saiyan transformation or can anyone attain it?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

We know that Super Saiyan, Super Saiyan 2, Super Saiyan 3, Super Saiyan God, Super Saiyan Blue, Super Saiyan Rage, Legendary Super Saiyan, Super Saiyan Berserker, Super Saiyan Evolution, etc. are all Saiyan transformations, they can only be achieved by Saiyans. But what about Ultra Instinct? Could a human, a Namekian, a frost demon, etc. attain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this question can be drawn from a few scenes from Episode 110 of Dragon Ball Super:

- Lord Beerus saying what transformation Goku might have gone through:

  [image: "Ultra Instinct..."]
- Lord Champa in shock after hearing what Beerus said:

  [image]
- The Supreme Kai realizing how Goku's movements linked to what he knew:

  [image: "I see. Those movements..."]
- The Supreme Kai doubting Goku's ability to reach that transformation:

  [image: "But, for a mortal like Son Goku...?"]

  [image: "That is a state not even a god can easily attain."]
- The Gods being pressurized by Goku's transformation:

  [image: "It seems to be something rather well-known amongst the gods."]

All this would mean that it's not an exclusive Saiyan trait or transformation, but an extremely powerful and difficult ability that the Gods and other Omega level fighters are known to use.

Comment: And we see Whis fanboying in the background. Also, note that Ultra instinct is the technique that Whis was training Goku and Vegeta to use, Where each part of your body thinks and reacts for itself. Wondercricket's answer does an excellent job of pointing that out.

Comment: @Ryan: True. I thought it was obvious enough from just that scene that it wasn't Saiyan exclusive, since the question deals with the usability of that technique.

Answer (score 6):

I am not very keen on the Dragon Ball franchise, but based on the [Ultra Instinct](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Instinct) wiki, there are three individuals who use the Ultra Instinct - Only 1 of them is a Sayian

> Ultra Instinct (身勝手の極意 Migatte no Gokui, lit. Key of Egoism) is a mental state used by [Whis](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Whis) and his disciples, [Beerus](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Beerus) and [Goku](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku).

According to each individuals wikis, Whis is of the [Angel race](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Angel), Beerus is of the [Beeru's Race](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Beerus%27_Race), and Goku of the [Sayian race](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Saiyan). Seeing how the ability is a mental state of the individual, it is quite possible that other races are able to obtain this ability as well - although the prerequisites are not entirely clear, even to Goku

> It is not completely clear how this form is attained, not even to Goku himself.

However, this ability is also apparently extremely hard to master, even for gods

> It is notorious among the Supreme Kais and Gods of Destruction for being exceptionally difficult to master, even for gods. Goku attains this state during the Tournament of Power

Comment: I'm not sure how necessary it is, but a small improvement might be to note that the 3 are the only confirmed users of ultra instict, but not nessecarily the only ones capable of using it. There are 12 universes, and likely all 12 angels in them (Whis included) can probably use it, and several of the Gods of Destruction (Beerus included) too can probably to some degree use it. Not including the higher ranked individuals. Those 3 are just the only 3 we have direct proof of it being used, Goku in the anime only, Beerus in the manga (also mentioned in both), and Whis in both.